# Angular Error information in console does not show detail on which component / service the error occurred in

Tags: angular, debugging

Angular 8

I am finding it quite difficult debugging my Angular apps as errors are not including information that enable me to isolate where the error occurred.

For template errors this is Ok - the error tells me the component and the line number. However for code errors all I am getting is output that looks something like this.

```
Error [Error description]  vendor.js
 Stacktrace here
```

Or

```
Error [Error description] main.js
  Stacktrace here
```

Or

```
View_UserAlertsComponent_0 ng:///AppModule/UserAlertsComponent.ngfactory.js:75
```

The output appears to refer to the compiled code. Is there a way to get the source file and line number that the error was triggered in?

**UPDATE**

To demonstrate I deliberately added a call to a non-existent method in my component (in the template). The output is shown below

```
  ERROR TypeError: "_co.testing is not a function"
    View_SendToClientComponent_0 ng:///AppModule/SendToClientComponent.ngfactory.js:245
    debugUpdateRenderer http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:88108
    checkAndUpdateView http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87091
    callViewAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87451
    execComponentViewsAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87379
    checkAndUpdateView http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87092
    callViewAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87451
    execEmbeddedViewsAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87408
    checkAndUpdateView http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87086
    callViewAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87451
    execComponentViewsAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87379
    checkAndUpdateView http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87092
    callViewAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87451
    execEmbeddedViewsAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87408
    checkAndUpdateView http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87086
    callViewAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87451
    execComponentViewsAction http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87379
    checkAndUpdateView http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:87092
    callWithDebugContext http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:88426
    debugCheckAndUpdateView http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:88008
    detectChanges http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:75146
    tick http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:84047
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:83895
    invoke http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:3594
    onInvoke http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:82829
    invoke http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:3593
    run http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:3359
    run http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:82688
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:83892
    schedulerFn http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:79157
    __tryOrUnsub http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218340
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218279
    _next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218229
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218206
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:217992
    emit http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:79119
    checkStable http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:82772
    onLeave http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:82890
    onInvoke http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:82832
    invoke http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:3593
    run http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:3359
    run http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:82688
    runOutsideAngular http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:89108
    __tryOrUnsub http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218340
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218279
    _next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218229
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218206
    _next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:222701
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218206
    _tryNext http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:224082
    _next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:224069
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218206
    _next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:222701
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218206
    _next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:222701
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218206
    _next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218229
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218206
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:217992
    _next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218229
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:218206
    next http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:150011
    scheduleEvent http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:147836
    invokeTask http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:3626
    runTask http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:3403
    invokeTask http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:3700
    invoke http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:3689
    timer http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:5885
SendToClientComponent.ngfactory.js:215:42
```

Comment: are you using `ng serve` command to run and debug?

Comment: yes - running ng serve --port XXXX

Comment: In stacktrace you should get file name *.ts where issue has occurred. In stacktrace what file names you are getting?

Comment: .js files only - no .ts files. That is what my question is about - how to get the stacktrace to relate to the .ts files rather than the compiled .js files. To demonstrate I added a call to a non-existent component method. I have added the stacktrace to the question